# Is there any way to replace this laundy sink with a toilet without major renovations?

Tags: basement, toilet, sink, laundry

Looking to replace this basement laundry sink with a toilet. Definitely do not want to break into the concrete, and would prefer not to open the wall behind. Drain pipe from sink is 14 inches from the floor. Any info is appreciated. Thanks!

[image: behind sink]

[image: beside sink]

[image: front sink]

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to see if you can find a macerator (grinder/pump) toilet with an outlet compatible with the pipe size/location you have there. "Basement toilet" will often get results including those, for application to basements where the sewer exists above floor level.

Us doing so would be shopping, so it would be off topic, so I'm just telling you what you need to shop for if that's the approach you are taking to this potential replacement.

If the sewer exits below floor level, breaking concrete is absolutely the better, more reliable way to put a toilet there. A macerator toilet is a mechanical device subject to failures; it's also typically much more costly than a standard toilet.

Comment: I've looked into macerating, would like to avoid if possible. The sewer exits above floor level. Would it be possible to place a regular toilet on maybe a 16 inch platform and connect to this existing pipe?

Comment: No, that pipe is far too small for a toilet (other than, perhaps, a macerator). A regular toilet requires a bare minimum of a 3 inch (inside diameter) pipe.

Comment: A platform might also trigger a bunch of other building code items that won't be needed if you can keep the toilet at floor level - railings, ceiling height, etc. Your best path here is probably a macerator with a lift pump, though it won't be cheap.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the help!

Comment: It would give meaning to be on the throne, if it was raised.